# Multidex giving runtime error

Tags: android-multidex

I have enabled MultiDex in my application and when I am trying to put preDexLibraries = false in dexOptions it gives the following error

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException:
> Translation has been interrupted

If i run without preDexLibraries = false option, build gets successful but Appcrashes

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider
>
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class